# v3io, Limit for amount of files

Tags: limit, mlrun

Do you know limits or formula, how to calculate amount of files in v3io? It probably has relation to count of data nodes in cluster and size of memory on data server nodes.

I tried to use 50 and also 80 millions of files in v3io and it performs well, but it is important to know expected limits or general recommendation.

BTW: I do not have sample of code or better description for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of files in v3io depends on amount of data nodes and memory size of data nodes. You can see range between **90 millions** and **1 billion** of files. Detail see the table.

[image]