# MLRun, ErrorMessage, No space left on device

Tags: python, health-check, feature-store, mlrun

I got this error during ingest data to FeatureSet:

```
Error - Failed to save aggregation for /k78/online_detail/nosql/sets/on line_detail/0354467518.ed74fc2b
Response status code was 400: b'{\n\t"ErrorCode": -28,\n\t"ErrorMessage": "No space left on device"\n} 
Update expression was: pr_ph='0354467518';id=7309877;type='r77'
```

I used standard code for ingestion, see:

```
import mlrun
import mlrun.feature_store as fs
...
project = mlrun.get_or_create_project(project_name, context='./', user_project=False)
feature_set=featureGetOrCreate(True, project_name, 'sample')
...
fs.ingest(feature_set, df)
```

It seems as the issue with disk space, but I am 100% sure that I had enough free space for ingest (it will be something different). Did you have the similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in number of objects on side of data nodes and it has relation to these platform [limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76156946/v3io-limit-for-amount-of-files/76165404#76165404).

It is possible to run the **HealthCheckScript (hcs)** and see number of objects in v3io containers, see the command (with setting):

```
hcs -v --dark --test check_cluster_engine_number_of_objects
```

and you see these outputs:

```
...
[2023-05-25 20:30:20] [TASK] [check_cluster_engine_number_of_objects] Checking the number of objects in the cluster.
[2023-05-25 20:30:20] [SUBTASK] Checking the data cluster's operational status...
[2023-05-25 20:30:21] [INFO] The data cluster is online.
[2023-05-25 20:30:21] [SUBTASK] Counting the number of objects in each container...
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] +----------------+------+----------+
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] | Container Name | ID   | Items    |
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] +----------------+------+----------+
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] | projects       | 1033 | 28715350 |
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] | users          | 1034 | 179598   |
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] | bigdata        | 1035 | 271      |
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] | users          | 1036 | 285995   |
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] | Total          |      | 29181214 |
[2023-05-25 20:30:30] [INFO] +----------------+------+----------+
...
```

BTW: The **hcs** command is available on side of data nodes.