# Iguazio, Errno 28

Tags: diskspace, mlrun

I got this error in Iguazio '[Errno 28] No space left on device', see information from log:

```
2023-08-04 08:53:16,283 [error] runtime error: [('/v3io/projects/krt/FeatureStore/tracing/parquet/sets/tracing/1689173417362_445/part_date=20230719/850ad77c-008e-4a7c-a83c-91be7e7c0e04.parquet', '/v3io/projects/krt/FeatureStore/tracing/test/20230719/part_date=20230719/850ad77c-008e-4a7c-a83c-91be7e7c0e04.parquet', "
2023-08-04 08:53:17,582 [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/v3io/projects/krt/FeatureStore/tracing/test/20230719/part_date=20230719/850ad77c-008e-4a7c-a83c-91be7e7c0e04.parquet'
```

It is typically issue with not enough disk space, but I allocated only 20% of disk space.

Did you solve the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The error message `[Errno 28] No space left on device` has not only relation to `'not enough disk space'`, but it has relation to amount of objects in v3io file system.

I got this error because, I was near to the limit for amount of objects (it has relation to configuration of data nodes), see [full clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76156946/v3io-limit-for-amount-of-files/76165404#76165404).